# Select tag rails to follow key punched for numerics

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have a select tag for time.

```
  = select_tag "depart-minute", options_for_select('00'..'59', dep_minute), :include_blank => true'
```

When this select field is on focus and i press 5 two time, it show 51 that's the second item in the list starts with 5.

what i want is, when i press 5 two times, it should show 55.

can it be possible?

Comment: This is html behaviour, it has nothing to do with Rails or haml... You might try to solve this using javascript on the client (but that is beyond my knowledge).